# EC2 instances login with password and keypair

Tags: ssh, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, passwords, key

I understand that by default Amazon EC2 configures a keypair with a default instance user (user-ec2 or ubuntu) for SSH access. Also I understand that it is possible to allow password access to a specified user by (PasswordAuthentication yes). Now, it is possible to force both factors as an authentication method? Forcing the administrator to use the keypair and to use the password.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not exactly. SSH authentication generally uses one or the other. However, you can protect your key with a passphrase which will be required before it can be used.